# Batch file - If statement and goto error

Tags: batch-file

Anything put into this part of this batch file automatically goes to :yes, regardless of whether the string is contained in MRSVANDERTRAMP.txt or not.

```
:enterverb
set /p id=Enter Verb: 

findstr /m %id% MRSVANDERTRAMP.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
goto :yes 
) else (
goto :no
)

:no
echo Verb does not take etre in the Perfect Tense. 
pause
goto :option0

:yes
echo Verb is a MRSVANDERTRAMP verb and takes etre in the Perfect Tense.
pause
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530976/how-to-conditionally-take-action-if-findstr-fails-to-find-a-string

Comment: Is there `:option0` tag  ? Because if not the code will always go trhough the yes part.

Comment: Yes, that is lower down (and not shown in this piece of the code).

Comment: why use `goto` when you can put the yes and no block in the if/else blocks already?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a similar code to test it, and it works.

```
@echo off
@title TEST

:main
set /p word=Write a word: 

findstr /M %word% words.txt

if "%errorlevel%" == "0" ( echo FOUND ) else ( echo NOT FOUND )
pause>nul
cls && goto main
```

---

Maybe there's a problem with the IF statement..
Try using

```
if "%errorlevel%" == "0"
```

insead of

```
if %errorlevel%==0
```

Comment: This does seem to work, and fixes another problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.  You might like to surround `"%id%"` in double quotes as shown, to protect against some poison characters though.

```
@echo off

echo one>MRSVANDERTRAMP.txt
echo two>>MRSVANDERTRAMP.txt


:enterverb
set /p id=Enter Verb: 

findstr /m %id% MRSVANDERTRAMP.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
goto :yes 
) else (
goto :no
)

:no
echo Verb does not take etre in the Perfect Tense. 
pause
goto :option0

:yes
echo Verb is a MRSVANDERTRAMP verb and takes etre in the Perfect Tense.
pause

:option0
echo done
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude try this

enterverb

```
set /p id=Enter Verb: 
findstr /m %id% MRSVANDERTRAMP.txt

set a=0

if %errorlevel%== %a% (
goto :yes 
) else (
goto :no
)

:no
echo Verb does not take etre in the Perfect Tense. 
pause
goto :option0

:yes
echo Verb is a MRSVANDERTRAMP verb and takes etre in the Perfect Tense.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in this code:

```
@echo off

ping www.google.com
if %errorlevel%== 0 (
goto :ok
) else (
go to :fail
)

:ok
echo ok
pause

:fail
echo fail
pause
```

Always go to `:ok`
but with a set off `var=0` my problem is solved and my code runs.

```
@echo off
ping www.google.com
set a=0
if %errorlevel%== %a% (
goto :ok
) else (
goto :fail
)

:ok
echo ok
pause


:fail
echo fail
pause
```