# Check if variable contains a piece of text in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Variable = %version%

This variable contains this = 5.13-update_01-01-2014

How can use the IF statement to check if the variable %version% contains the word '**update**' ??

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple demo using conditional statements.

Look at this post (dbenham's answer) for a similar question [How to conditionally take action if FINDSTR fails to find a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530976/how-to-conditionally-take-action-if-findstr-fails-to-find-a-string)

```
C:\>set variable=5.13_01-01-2014

C:\>(echo %variable% | findstr /i /c:"update" >nul) && (echo Variable contains the string "update") || (echo Variable does not have the string "update")
Variable does not have the string "update"

C:\>set variable=5.13-update_01-01-2014

C:\>(echo %variable% | findstr /i /c:"update" >nul) && (echo Variable contains the string "update") || (echo Variable does not have the string "update")
Variable contains the string "update"
```

Cheers,G

Comment: Thx dude! Super quick reaction! :p