# How to check if environment variable contains specific string (in a BATCH file)

Tags: batch-file

I have tried this but it doesn't work because variable (PATH environment variable)contains spaces: [Check if variable contains a piece of text in BATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180468/check-if-variable-contains-a-piece-of-text-in-batch?lq=1)

Comment: I see no reason, why the linked solution wouldn't work with spaces. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

Much depends on the string you are attempting to detect. Some examples would be helpful.

Perhaps

```
if "%path:yourstring=%" neq "%path%" echo String found
```

would work in your particular situation, but without a few details, it's little more than a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The path variable can contain quotes and special characters like `"C:\Docs & other stuff"`.
Therefore, it's a good idea to use delayed instead of percent expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!path:%myVar%=!" NEQ "!path!" echo path contains !myVar!
```