# How do I check if installation succeeded after using "adb install file.apk"?

Tags: android, batch-file, adb, apk, android-install-apk

I install an apk from Windows PC using

```
adb install file.apk
```

The result could be "Success" or one of the Failure messages.
How do I determine whether the installation succeeded within the batch file? I want to move the apk of successful installation to another folder.

Comment: What about using as first line `adb install file.apk | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe  /C /I "Success" >nul` and as second line `if errorlevel 1 goto Failure` with `Failure` being a label in batch file handling installation error condition? The console application `find` searches case-insensitive for `Success` in output lines of `adb` and output the number of lines containing this string which is redirected to device NUL. The exit code is checked by second line which is not 0 if the string `Success` could not be found by `find` in any line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally take action if FINDSTR fails to find a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530976/how-to-conditionally-take-action-if-findstr-fails-to-find-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

`adb install file.apk>NUL && echo Action done successfully || echo Action Failed`

Comment: This returns "Action done successfully" all the time. Please explain why do you expect this to work?

Comment: Explanation is here http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php As fas as I have not 'adb' program, tested with ping comand and work fine: If ping target reachable (errorlevel 0) echo "Action done successfully", if unreachable (errorlevel 1) echo "Action Failed"

Comment: this actually works with the latest versions of Android and `adb`. But until very recently `adb` did not set the `errorlevel` in accordance with the result of the command. So for now checking for presence of the "Success" string in the output is the only way for most people.